# Crear librería .so a partir de librerias .h y cpp, para usarse con python en raspberry pi

Tags: python, c++, arduino, librería

¿Cómo podría crear una librería .so a partir de que tengo varios archivos .h y .cpp?

Tengo un algoritmo que funciona para poder escribir/leer en tarjetas RFID, pero este algoritmo solamente lo tengo funcionando con **Arduino**. Entonces mi interés es que ya las librerías que tengo en .h y .cpp de Arduino las haga funcionar en python. Había leído en algun articulo sobre que podria hacer un archivo cython y luego ese archivo pasarlo a librería .so para poder utilizar este .so en la raspberry e invocar los metodos desde python.

Pero también he visto que hay muchos caminos para lograr esto, pero no me queda muy claro..¿Alguien que me puede aconsejar o ayudar con su expertise?

Estas son las librerias que tengo funcionando en Arduino, son 8:

[image: Librerías funcionables en Arduino]

La librería principal es **Desfire3.h** de donde creo la instancia para usar los metodos correspondientes.

Comment: Hay una forma simple de generar un archivo `.so`. Compilando el código. Si no sabes cómo, dinos que compilador estás usando.

Comment: No uso ningún compilador, todo lo estoy haciendo desde visual stuidio code para editar los archivos y el IDE de Arduino para subirlo a la placa.

Comment: Entonces el IDE de Arduino está compilando las cosas, supone uno. Nada sube a la placa sin compilar... por cierto, el código se comparte como texto. Desde el móvil no veo nada y es imposible ayudarte. Otros intentarán replicar tu problema y elegirán no intentarlo porque transcribir es tedioso.

Comment: Vale, si es que lo subí en imagen ya que no creo que sea necesario que se vea mi codigo en sí, solo busco la manera de una solución para realizar un archivo .so de las librerias que ya tengo.